# Development schema not matching with Production schema. Rake aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am in my deployment stage of my application and found a few errors...   I am using Capistrano and Mongrel for the purpose and the deploy.rb file is like this

```
set :application, "ngs_app"
set :repository,  "file:///Users/Admin/svnrepo/#{application}"
set :deploy_to,   "/Library/WebServer/#{application}"
set :deploy_via,  :export
set :scm_username, "Admin"
set :scm_password, "##########"
set :scm, :subversion
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true

# Or: `accurev`, `bzr`, `cvs`, `darcs`, `git`, `mercurial`, `perforce`, `subversion` or `none`

role :web, "130.209.53.216"                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, "130.209.53.216"                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  "130.209.53.216", :primary => true        # This is where Rails migrations will run
# role :db,  "your slave db-server here"
# Adding Mongrel_specific variables
set :mongrel_cmd, "/usr/bin/mongrel_rails_persist"
set :mongrel_ports, 3000..3003
set :user, "Admin"
set :group, "administrator"

# Adding Capistrano tasks 
namespace :deploy do
desc "Start Mongrel processes and add them to launchd. "
task :start, :roles => :app do 
  mongrel_ports.each do |port|
    sudo "#{mongrel_cmd} start -p #{port} -e production --user #{user} --group #{group} -c #{current_path}"
  end
end
desc "Stop mongrels processess and remove them from launchd. "
task :stop, :roles => :app do 
  mongrel_ports.each do |port|
    sudo "#{mongrel_cmd} stop -p #{port}"
  end
end
desc "Restart Mongrel processes"
task :restart, :roles => :app do 
  stop 
  start
end
end

The error message I get are the following

sudo cap deploy:cold
  * executing `deploy:cold'
  * executing `deploy:update'
** transaction: start
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
    executing locally: "svn info file:///Users/Admin/svnrepo/ngs_app --username Admin --password colonsay2010 --no-auth-cache  -rHEAD"
    command finished in 9ms
  * executing "svn export -q --username Admin --password colonsay2010 --no-auth-cache  -r2 file:///Users/Admin/svnrepo/ngs_app /Library/WebServer/ngs_app/releases/20110912144920 && (echo 2 > /Library/WebServer/ngs_app/releases/20110912144920/REVISION)"
    servers: ["130.209.53.216"]
Password: 
    [130.209.53.216] executing command
    command finished in 704ms
  * executing `deploy:finalize_update'
  * executing "chmod -R g+w /Library/WebServer/ngs_app/releases/20110912144920"
    servers: ["130.209.53.216"]
    [130.209.53.216] executing command
    command finished in 31ms
  * executing "rm -rf /Library/WebServer/ngs_app/releases/20110912144920/log /Library/WebServer/ngs_app/releases/20110912144920/public/system /Library/WebServer/ngs_app/releases/20110912144920/tmp/pids &&\\\n      mkdir -p /Library/WebServer/ngs_app/releases/20110912144920/public &&\\\n      mkdir -p /Library/WebServer/ngs_app/releases/20110912144920/tmp &&\\\n      ln -s /Library/WebServer/ngs_app/shared/log /Library/WebServer/ngs_app/releases/20110912144920/log &&\\\n      ln -s /Library/WebServer/ngs_app/shared/system /Library/WebServer/ngs_app/releases/20110912144920/public/system &&\\\n      ln -s /Library/WebServer/ngs_app/shared/pids /Library/WebServer/ngs_app/releases/20110912144920/tmp/pids"
    servers: ["130.209.53.216"]
    [130.209.53.216] executing command
    command finished in 21ms
  * executing "find /Library/WebServer/ngs_app/releases/20110912144920/public/images /Library/WebServer/ngs_app/releases/20110912144920/public/stylesheets /Library/WebServer/ngs_app/releases/20110912144920/public/javascripts -exec touch -t 201109121449.25 {} ';'; true"
    servers: ["130.209.53.216"]
    [130.209.53.216] executing command
    command finished in 100ms
  * executing `deploy:symlink'
  * executing "rm -f /Library/WebServer/ngs_app/current && ln -s /Library/WebServer/ngs_app/releases/20110912144920 /Library/WebServer/ngs_app/current"
    servers: ["130.209.53.216"]
    [130.209.53.216] executing command
    command finished in 10ms
** transaction: commit
  * executing `deploy:migrate'
  * executing "cd /Library/WebServer/ngs_app/releases/20110912144920 && rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate"
    servers: ["130.209.53.216"]
    [130.209.53.216] executing command
*** [err :: 130.209.53.216] rake aborted!
*** [err :: 130.209.53.216] 
*** [err :: 130.209.53.216] An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:
*** [err :: 130.209.53.216] 
*** [err :: 130.209.53.216] SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: organism: ALTER TABLE "samples" ADD "organism" varchar(255)
*** [err :: 130.209.53.216] 
*** [err :: 130.209.53.216] 
*** [err :: 130.209.53.216] (See full trace by running task with --trace)
*** [err :: 130.209.53.216] 
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] (in /Library/WebServer/ngs_app/releases/20110912144920)
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] ==  CreateBatches: migrating ==================================================
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] -- create_table(:batches)
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] -> 0.0012s
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] ==  CreateBatches: migrated (0.0013s) =========================================
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] 
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] ==  CreateSamples: migrating ==================================================
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] -- create_table(:samples)
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] -> 0.0020s
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] ==  CreateSamples: migrated (0.0021s) =========================================
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] 
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] ==  AddMajorToBatch: migrating ================================================
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] -- add_column(:batches, :submit_date, :date)
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] -> 0.0007s
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] -- add_column(:batches, :grp_leader, :string)
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] -> 0.0004s
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] -- add_column(:batches, :contact_person, :string)
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] -> 0.0003s
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] -- add_column(:batches, :batch_comment, :text)
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] -> 0.0003s
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] ==  AddMajorToBatch: migrated (0.0019s) =======================================
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] 
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] ==  AddSecondToBatch: migrating ===============================================
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] -- add_column(:batches, :sample_type, :string)
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] -> 0.0007s
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] -- add_column(:batches, :extraction, :string)
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] -> 0.0004s
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] -- add_column(:batches, :cleanup, :string)
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] -> 0.0004s
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] -- add_column(:batches, :suspension, :string)
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] -> 0.0003s
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] ==  AddSecondToBatch: migrated (0.0020s) ======================================
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] 
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] ==  AddThirdToBatch: migrating ================================================
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] -- add_column(:batches, :preparation, :string)
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] -> 0.0013s
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] -- add_column(:batches, :sequencing, :string)
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] -> 0.0004s
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] ==  AddThirdToBatch: migrated (0.0019s) =======================================
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] 
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] ==  AddThingsToSample: migrating ==============================================
** [out :: 130.209.53.216] -- add_column(:samples, :organism, :string)
    command finished in 1722ms
failed: "sh -c 'cd /Library/WebServer/ngs_app/releases/20110912144920 && rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate'" on 130.209.53.216
```

Can some one help me out y the rake is getting aborted....?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Some of the possibilities are as below:

- Somebody modified the existing db_migration_XXX.rb script. From the production DB perspective this script was already run
- There are more than one intended actions in the DB migration script and if the script was aborted for the first time when it was run and you try to re-run the script, this kind of issue typically occurs.